# USB-C power delivery from a DC source

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, dc, usb-c

I have a fixed DC voltage - say within the range of 12-24 V. I'm looking to take this voltage supply and run it through some sort of circuitry so that I can have a USB-C female port, say on a desk or wall port, capable of charging various devices such as phones, laptops, etc.

I am familiar with the fact that the USB-C protocol can utilize communication protocol to select the appropriate power to deliver to a specific device. I have seen the reverse of what I'm looking for in various videos in that power is taken from a power source via USB-C before it's converted to a DC source depending on the power delivery capabilities of the source.

Is there an existing board capable of doing this? I understand that perhaps the circuitry would need to communicate first with the device connected first at a 5 V level, before being capable of stepping up power delivery to match that of the connected device. So this may require some logic/stepping-down of power.

Some research led to the TPS65982 chip by Texas Instruments - but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. Any suggestion/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The STUSB4500 is a common USB-PD controller.  You can buy "trigger" boards or download example schematics from github.

Comment: @user1850479 perfect - just to verify this will handle the "handshake" protocol between the USB C compatible device and controller?

Comment: @user1850479 maybe I am mistaken - but looking at several sources online this chip appears to be used to take USB C power and convert it to a DC voltage to charge something. What I intend to do is the opposite, take a DC voltage and charge a USB C enabled device such as a phone or laptop

Comment: You're not mistaken, the STUSB4500 is for a PD sink device. You want something like the STUSB4700 which is for a PD source device. By the way, despite them commonly being referred to as chargers, they're simply power supplies - the charging circuits will be part of the sink device.

Comment: I'm also looking for the same thing, but I'm really struggling to find a reasonably priced source board. I'm ideally looking for something that can handle 18v and/or 48v DC (ideally a range) as the input for two different use cases I have.

Comment: @GordonRudman, shopping questions are off-topic on the site. See the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

The [XY-PDS100](https://m.fasttech.com/product/9730673-xy-pds100-dual-usb-fast-charger-converter-module) does exactly what you want.

It can take 12-24 V DC input and provide USB-C PD and QC. The only downside is that it's a step-down converter, so you can't get 20 V from it when the input is 12 V.